# Set Color for individual Treeview items based on data not bound to the treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this.  I have a treeview that is using Hierarchal data from sql server tables.  Using linq to generate the dbml and then binding the data to the treeview.  Here is the part I am having trouble with.  Say the treeview starts and goes Categories----->Authors----->Books------>CheckedOut

So If I wanted to color each item(red) and all the parent nodes(red) where the item is overdue based on a view I created in sql server (I have four different categories to highlight based on dates stored in the db) what would be the best approach for this in C# WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a style trigger to trigger action when item in your tree view item  meets certain condition

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlight}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="youcolor" />
                 </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
```